# How can I display a Angularjs Object?

Tags: angularjs

How do I display the content of a AngularJS Object in a string format like when we alert a variable?

Comment: Nor sure I understood correctly but are you asking how to display variable content? Use console: in you controller code `console.log($scope.myvar)`

Comment: Or just `<pre ng-bind="myObject | json"></pre>`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want from an object either:

```
$log.debug('Some message', theObject);
```

Advantages: you can leave it inproduction but disable output using $logProvider and for most browsers the object displays collapsed until you expand it. The disadvantage is that you have to find an appropriate place to insert the call and you may get a torrent of debug messages more than you want.

Or you can use `$log.error()` which at least on Chrome has the advantage of including a stacktrace in the console log.

Or, insert into your html:

```
<pre>{{theObject|json:4}}</pre>
```

The advantage is the current value is present in your page, it's always there so you can look at it whenever you want and there's no torrent of messages. Disadvantages are that the object has to be convertible to json, you won't see all of the properties (e.g. any functions it contains or properties beginning with '$'), you have to store the object in a scope, and you don't get the history.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `console.log` instead of alert. It's more flexible. You will see logged values in browser console.

Comment: <h4>Your role is :${roles}</h4> this line is there in my jsp page and i want to display the value of  ${roles} in controller.

Comment: `${...}` is not angular's interpolation. It's from JSP! You can [log it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_debugging.htm) on server side.